# Name Parameters dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, parameters

Just imagine this simple situation:

```
int temperature = 20;
```

is there any possibility to give a dynamic parameter name?? Like for example (I know that doesn't work, just to get the idea) :

```
int Array[1].ToString() = 20;
```

Thank you!
Cheers Chris

Comment: I'd say no, but --- What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The example you provided that you know doesn't work but it's meant to give us the idea... I don't get the idea. In fact, I'm quite dumbfounded.

Comment: Perhaps [Dictionary<K,V>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not in C#. The closest you could get would be to use a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
var variables = new Dictionary<string, object>();

variables.Add(Array[1].ToString(), 20);
```

But not only does that involve casting each time you need to retrieve the value, but it will also cause boxing/unboxing.

All told, I certainly wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can play with the dynamic/Expando objects in C# 4

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Foo(dynamic duck)
    {
        duck.Quack(); // Called dynamically
    }

    static void Foo(Guid ignored)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Calls Foo(dynamic) statically
        Foo("hello");
    }
}
```

and follow that link [Link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741%28VS.100%29.aspx)